# What is the use of defining <ui:fragment> tag in jsf

Tags: jsf, fragment, facelets

I am new to JSF. I read about  tag. But I find only examples not about when to use and what if we don't use it?
 I want to know what is the real requirement for use of `<ui:fragment>` tag.

Is it really necessary at any point?

Can some body explain me with and without this what could be the output?

Comment: @BalusC I couldn't find a help from the link given. I google everywhere. But all says how to use but no where I could find when to use.

Answer (score 6):

This is what i found by observing my existing project. Anybody can correct me if I am wrong.

I think this can be used, if you want to display some component based on the condition. So inside `<ui:fragment>` attribute `'rendered'` can be used to control the display of fragment.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{rowStatus.index % 2 == 0}">
         <tr>
            <td width="16%">#{slots.dateStr}</td>
            <td width="65%">Day #{rowStatus.index + 1} (#{dailySlots.weekStr})</td>
                                <td width="4%">PM</td>
         </tr>
  </ui:fragment>
```